# How to clear a text field on click and also change it's color

Tags: javascript, css

I have a search text box with an initial value of "Search" and a gray color.

When it is clicked, I want to clear the text and set the color to black so when the User stats typing, it is in black.

I have this so far and it clears fine. I tried to add a css style to it but its gives me a syntax error: the attribute is missing the attribute name following the namespace.

```
 onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search'; }"

 onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; style="color: #000000;"; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search'; }"
```

Comment: @Ankit Depends if an older browser needs support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to set the color would be to change the color property on the style property of the DOM element, so something like

```
 this.style.color = ...
```

So, if you want to support IE9 or something similar

```
<input onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000000'; }" onblur="    if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search'; this.style.color = 'red'; }" value="Search" style="color: red" />
```

Otherwise, Ankit's answer would be the right way to go

Comment: I know this is what OP really asked for but what if someone types Search ;)

Comment: @Ankit - I think one way to do it would be to use a nonprintable character after the word Search, so that there's less (but still not 0 :-)) chance that its a something the user wants to search for.

Comment: Yep that could be a way or add some class to store the state of the inputs

Comment: @Ankit - oh yeah, that's the better way!  Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to support IE9 and below then

You should use placeholder attribute with some CSS like

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #555; }
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #555; }
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #555; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #555; }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```